# Save Files To New Directory (Fortran)

Tags: file, directory, save, fortran

I am trying to open a file from a directory, format the file, then place it in a new directory.

Here's what I have so far.

```
open(11,file='/home/folder1/directories/directory1/data.txt,form='formatted')
close(11)
```

I know I'll have a write statement after opening the file, but I'm stuck on how to save it to a new directory.

The directory I want to place the reformatted file is /home/folder1/directories/directory2

Comment: What are you trying to do *exactly*? Why don't you simply `read` in the file contents, `open` a second file, and `write` the data back to the second file?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to open the new file and write to it.

```
open(11,file='/home/folder1/directories/directory1/data.txt,form='formatted')
open(12,file='/home/folder1/directories/directory2/data.txt,form='formatted', status='new')

! loop over records
do ...
   ! read record
   read(11,IN_FORMAT,...) ...

   ! write record
   write(12,OUT_FORMAT,...) ...
end do

close(11)
close(12)
```